# TableTreeView (JavaFx 8): Cannot set font color of label in cell

Tags: javafx, scalafx

I have a TreeTableView control in my view, which has a column, which is composed of two labels. That is during runtime a cell is rendered by displaying two labels:

```
class ItemCell extends TreeTableCell[InventoryModelItem, InventoryModelItem] {

val hbox = new HBox()
val actionLabel = new Label()
actionLabel.styleClass.add("label-hotkey")
val itemLabel = new Label()
hbox.children.addAll(actionLabel, itemLabel)
setGraphic(hbox)

override def updateItem(item: InventoryModelItem, empty: Boolean): Unit = {
if (!empty && item != null) {
  actionLabel.setText(item.action.getOrElse(""))
  itemLabel.setText(item.displayName)
}

//setTextFill(Color.BLUE);
//setStyle("-fx-background-color: yellow");

}
}
```

What I wanna achieve is that the action label is rendered with a different style. Thus I set it via actionLabel.styleClass.add("label-hotkey"). The css style is recognized in general:

```
.label-hotkey {
-fx-font-size: 11pt;
-fx-font-family: "Droid Sans Mono";
-fx-text-fill: yellow;
-fx-opacity: 0.6;
}
```

For instance the -fx-font-size is taken into account during rendering. The issue is that -fx-text-fill is ignored, so the color of the label is not yellow.

So, what I am doing wrong here ?

EDIT: Even setTextFill(Color.BLUE) has no effect (see commented section in coding)

Comment: Most likely the `TreeTableView`'s (or `TreeTableCell`'s) default style is overriding it. Did you try nesting the style under `.tree-table-view`? E.g. `.tree-table-view .label-hotkey { ... }`

Comment: @OttPrime The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) states "Styles loaded from a Scene's style sheets take precedence over selectors from the user agent style sheet." So the styles defined here should override anything defined in the default stylesheet.

Comment: @OttPrime no, it has no effect

Comment: It doesn't surprise me that `setTextFill(Color.BLUE)` has no effect: that sets the text fill of the cell, and you never set any text on the cell (only a graphic). You're sure your `actionLabel` actually has text in it...? No other ideas.

Comment: Yes, the content, also the font is displayed